# get time of task starting on worker

Tags: flask, celery

I need to get time of task starting on worker (WORKER_NAME) and have some problems with it.

```
# create task
task = some_func.delay(arg1, arg2)

# get time of this task start

task_time_start = inspect().active().get(WORKER_NAME)[0].get('time_start')

# worker is WORKER_NAME, it can run only one (now) task at time.
```

but when i make POST request (using `curl`) i have the following error:

```
task_time_creation = inspect().active().get(WORKER_NAME)[0].get('time_start')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i think it is because my task has already done up to this call and there are no `active` tasks in worker.

How can i get the real time of task start on worker?

I thought that there is a field in `AsyncResult` object (look https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html) but i didn't find anything about start time task there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this. The first is to use [`task_prerun`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-prerun) signal. Another approach is to monitor [Celery events](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing) and process the [`task-started`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#task-started) event. For this you have to set [`worker_send_task_events`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-send-task-events) config option (or alternatively start the worker with `-E` option). You might also need to set [`task_track_started`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-track-started).